# Can't get custom syntax highlight to work

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I can't get custom syntax highlight of the LaTeX \footnote command to work. I'm using nvim 0.4.3 through VimR.

I put the following in `./.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim` (Edit: my runtimepath is ./.vim/ instead of ./.config/  -- I did try to put the file in ./.config/after/syntax/ but to no avail)

```
syntax match footnote "footnote"
highlight link footnote Todo
```

(I intend to use a regex pattern later, if I can get this simple version to work)
Nothing happens when I type the command in a random .tex file. Not even after I do `:set syntax=tex` and not even with a minimal .vimrc with all plugins disabled.

Checking `:scriptnames` I see that the custom file is loaded as one of the very last files, right after the default syntax file in my VimR installation. The indent/tex.vim in my VimR installation is loaded even later.

Comment: Your config root must be `~/.config/nvim`

Comment: @Matt not necessarily, a lot of users have `set runtimepath^=~/.vim` in their `init.vim` so that their configuration is shared between vim and neovim. But it's still worth to check the output of `set runtimepath` to make sure this is the case @ Timothy.

Comment: @statox Really? Isn't a dir symlink simpler?

Comment: It can be, I guess it depends on everyone's preference. But I know I've seen this `set runtimepath` in a several configs, maybe because of one popular blog post somewhere which encourage every new neovim user to do that without having a second thought :)

Comment: Just to make sure I have edited my config root. Everything is now in `.config/nvim/` but the problem persists.

Comment: Update: it does work now, in an empty .tex file and in the preamble of a normal .tex file, but not in the body (eg after a \section command). No idea why yet, any pointers welcome.